# PHP Submit recorre ao ficheiro errado

Tags: php, javascript

Boas pessoal estou com um problema no meu código eu tenho 2 forms em que um faz o login e o outro faz o register, eu estou a usar um template one page, e estou a ter uns problemas. Eu quando faço o register esta tudo ok sem problemas, o problema é quando faço o login. Eu estou a usar 3 ficheiros para cada coisa, um que tem o html que é onde esta o código de ambos os forms, tenho 1 para connect a BD que é o que estou a usar para os 2 também, e tenho outro para conectar a tabela e pedir os dados que eu necessito, tendo cada um o seu. Eu no inicio de cada form no html estou a pedir as informações do devido ficheiro sendo o do login loginpro.php como podem ver no código abaixo.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function submitform()
    {
       document.forms["as"].submit();
    }
</script>
<form name="as" method="POST" action="loginpro.php">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
    <input style="font-size: 17px" type=button onClick="submitform()" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

O meu problema é que quando eu tento fazer o login não tenta usar o loginpro.php mas sim o regpro.php que é o ficheiro que uso para o register como também podem ver no código abaixo.

```
<script language="javascript">
function submitform()
{
   document.forms["register"].submit();
}
</script>
<center>
<form name="register" method="POST" action="regpro.php">
     Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br /><br />
     Email: <input type="text" name="Email" /><br /><br />
     First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br /><br />
     Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br /><br />
     Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
     <input style="font-size: 11px" type=button onClick="submitform()" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

Se me puderem ajudar fico muito agrecido porque preciso de isto pronto com alguma urgência.

Comment: Oras, sua função `submitform()` está sendo usada pros dois forms. E ela dá o submit no mesmo form sempre. Tens de usar uma função pra cada form ou passar um parâmetro dizendo qual dos forms deve ser submitado.

Comment: Por que você usa um javascript se você pode usar simplesmente um `<input type="submit">` ? Do que jeito que está ai, dá na mesma... pq você não está agregando nada ao submit...

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Eu tentei com esse codigo e estava a funcionar mas o template que o meu cliente me pediu para usar não permite enviar sem ser com java.

Comment: @Earendul Eu estou a usar um submitform() para cada um eu é que me esqueci de copiar o codigo do JS para o registar.

Comment: Então edite sua pergunta e coloque o código que esqueceste, ;)

Comment: Tente alterar sua função para receber parâmetros, assim acredito que você está sempre sobrescrevendo a mesma função e por isso deve gerar esse problema.

Comment: @Earendul feito ,eu sou novo na programação web por isso é normal se eu cometer alguns erros mas agradeço a ajuda

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Podes me dar uma ideia de como o posso fazer por favor.

Comment: Não sei se vai dar certo mas.... tente alterar seu input para type="submit" e coloque o evento no form assim onSubmit="submitform(this)"; Resultado final ficaria algo assim: `<script>
 function formsubmit(form) {
  form.submit();
 }
</script>
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="formsubmit(this)">
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>`

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Obrigado já esta tudo a funcionar graças a ti muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

## Problema

Dado que indicaste estares a utilizar um template "página única", isso diz-nos que tens todo o código a ser servidor ao mesmo tempo, o que levanta um problema com as tuas funções de JavaScript:

```js
function submitform() {
   document.forms["as"].submit();
}
```

E depois mais a baixo:

```js
function submitform() {
   document.forms["register"].submit();
}
```

Acontece que em JavaScript, se usas o mesmo nome para duas ou mais funções, a última é quem prevalece.

Assim sendo, sempre que usas `onClick="submitform()"`, estás a chamar sempre a mesma função, a última que estiver presente na tua página.

## Solução

Tens várias maneiras de resolver este assunto, cada uma mais adequada consoante o crescimento do trabalho que estás a realizar:

1. Funções com nomes específicos

   Nomes genéricos para funções, assumem um trabalho genérico, pelo que, dado cada função estar a lidar com um formulário específico, porque não usar:

   ```
   function submitLogin() {
     document.forms["as"].submit();
   }
   ```

   e

   ```
   function submitRegister() {
     document.forms["register"].submit();
   }
   ```
2. Submeter formulário normalmente

   É dificil aperceber-nos do que é normal nos dias de hoje dado o abuso na forma como as páginas são programadas só porque é fixe, mas de facto, a forma normal de um formulário ser submetido é através do próprio HTML:

   ```
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
   ```

   Um `<input/>` do tipo [`submit`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/submit) é um elemento com um atributo criado para dizer ao navegador que deverá enviar os dados do formulário para o servidor quando clicado.

Answer (score 1):

Concordo com o @Zuul que o ideal é não usar JS desnecessariamente, como neste caso.

De qualquer forma, um simples ajuste na função submit pode ajudar:

```
// Adicionamos o parametro "meuForm" na funcao
function submitform( meuForm )
{
   document.forms[ meuForm ].submit();
}
```

E nos forms, você chama a função com o nome certo:

```
<form name="as" method="POST" action="loginpro.php">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
    <input style="font-size: 17px" type=button onClick="submitform( 'as' )" value="Submit"/>
                               //  Aqui você põe o nome do form      ^


 <input style="font-size: 11px" type=button onClick="submitform( 'register' )" value="Submit"/>
                               //  Mesma coisa no segundo           ^
```